# Examples of matrix groups with centralizer isomorphic to $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, division-algebras

By Schur's Lemma, the centralizer $C(G)$ of an *irreducible* matrix groups $G\subseteq\mathrm{GL}(\Bbb R^d)$ is an $\Bbb R$-division algebra, and thus, isomorphic to either $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb H$ (the quaternions). I always had the feeling that $C(G)\cong \Bbb R$ is the generic case. This is because I only know the example $G\cong \mathrm U(1)$ (considered as a real matrix group of dimension two) with $C(G)\cong\Bbb C$. I do not know an example for $C(G)\cong\Bbb H$ at all.

> **Questions:**
>
> - What examples are there with $C(G)\cong \Bbb H$?
> - What other examples are there with $C(G)\cong \Bbb C$?
> - Have the groups with a given centralizer been "classified" in some sense? That is, is there a result of the form "all $G$ with $C(G)\cong \Bbb C$ are of the following form: ..." or the like?

Note that I want $G$ to be irreducible! But I don't care whether $G$ is finite or a Lie group or not nice at all.

Comment: For $C*G)\cong {\mathbb C}$, take $G=U(n)$ regarded as a subgroup of $GL(2d, {\mathbb R})$. I am not sure about quaternions. Lastly, I am not sure what the last question even means. For instance, there are many irreducible representations of $U(n)$. One can say that they are all built using a combination of some standard constructions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do all of the representations of $\mathrm U(n)$ have $\Bbb C$ as centralizer? And do you know whether the groups with a given centralizer have been classified?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I replaced the confusing third question, I hope this was okay.

Comment: All **irreducible** representations of $U(n)$ have ${\mathbb C}^*$ as the centralizer. If you like even more interesting examples, you can use irreducible representations of other simple Lie groups or restrictions of these to Zariski dense  subgroups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Great, thank you. How do I know which other Lie groups provide examples (other than subgroups of $\mathrm U(n)$)? And this is probably where my initial third question was aiming for: what is an intuition guiding me to decide whether a group has a certain centralizer? Is there something we know of $\mathrm U(n)$ that helps me to find further examples. Or isn't there anything like this and I have to inspect every group on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 3):

Well, that is just a homework exercise I set in my representation theory class a few weeks ago. (It is based on a problem I was given myself in a class I took in Aachen last milennium.) It is giving an example for which the endomorphism ring is $\mathbb{H}$. Since I'm lazy you get the problem text:

Let $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $G=\langle{
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
0&1\\%
-1&0\\%
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
i&0\\
0&-i\\%
\end{array}\right)%
}\rangle$ be the quaternion group of order 8.

a) Construct an irreducible representation of $G$ over the
real numbers, acting on a $4$-dimensional vectorspace $V\cong \mathbb{R}^4$.
( **Hint:** Use an $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}$ to get an $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$.
To show that no 2-dimensional
submodule exists, consider images of a nonzero vector $(a,b,c,d)$ in this subspace under different elements of $G$, and show that they will yield a basis of at least a 3-dimensional subspace.)

b) Determine the endomorphism ring $End_{\mathbb{R} G}(V)$.
(**Hint:** The elements of $End_{\mathbb{R} G}(V)$ are $4\times 4$ matrices that
commute with the generators of $G$. Use this to deduce conditions on their
entires. Then show that every matrix fulfilling these conditions commutes
with $G$.)

c) By Schur's lemma $End_{\mathbb{R} G}(V)$ must be a division ring. Can you
identify it?

Comment: Thank your for your answer! In retrospect, I remember that $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ was such a group. Now, i there an easy way to describe further groups with this centralizer?